# What do you call the practice of leaving the final word in a phrase unspoken?

Tags: vernacular

I cannot say for sure that Americans never do this, but some British speakers seem to leave off the last word in a (usually) set phrase. For example, the Cockney character Gerry Standing in the BBC series "New Tricks" told a suspect, "You stabbed her, you panicked, you ran. Simple as." He left off the last word, which presumably was "that" as in "Simple as that."

Similarly, the character Janet Scott in the ITV series "Scott & Bailey" says, "Now I don't give a monkey's." A monkey's what? "Posterior," perhaps. I keep thinking there must be a name for this practice. What is it?

I can imagine an American saying, "I don't give a rat's" although I can't recall ever hearing that usage, but it has the obvious advantage of avoiding the actual expression of the word "posterior" or any of its synonyms.

Comment: I would call it.

Comment: Good one..  @Hot

Comment: LOL. I would, .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly right but perhaps **aposiopesis** defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aposiopesis) as

> A figure of speech wherein a sentence is deliberately broken off and left unfinished, the ending to be supplied by the imagination, giving an impression of unwillingness or inability to continue.

Comment: Aposiopesis seems to be the word, although the strong emotion or reluctance to finish that is said to usually accompany it is most displayed in the Janet Scott example I gave, whereas the Gerry Standing quote seems to show strong emotion only incidentally. Gerry uses this form of speech whether he is agitated or in a good mood. I realize that the set expression “Get out or else!” is an example commonly found in American speech. Defiant targets of this command will often reply, “Or else what?!”

Comment: There ought to be a name for the omissions and side-stepping to stress the difference, isn’t a sentence deliberately broken off and left unfinished, ending to be supplied much more like the examples abounding on the WWW from the Bible and Ancient Greece through Shakespeare to The Hunt for Red October?

Most are more like:
▪ Don’t go there, or else…!
▪ If only…
▪ Why I oughta…
▪ How could you…?

By contrast ‘Simple as.’ is a wholly modern affectation more like, eg, ‘End of.’ both conveying shortness, sharpness and there being no point in further words.